# Isn't this question opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772810/mathematicians-ahead-of-their-time#) question. But I'm surprised to see it's not closed for being opinion-based. It looks like a poll actually. It doesn't cope with math itself.

There can even be 1000 answers and each answerer can think of a specific mathematician.

Comment: It's from almost 10 years ago. The standards for questions were fairly different then.

Comment: The old questions are excused from closure. They are the last paradise on this site.

Comment: *"paradise"* > *relics of ancient history*, and should be left buried the same way.

Comment: I've also wondered why past questions from the site got so many upvotes, despite how little effort was put into them.

Comment: @Gordon At first a fledgling site is happy to include everything. Then the reality of volume and quality sets in.

Comment: low quality is okay if you don't have too many people. The problem isn't low quality by itself. The problem is low quality  + too many ppl. Thats why rules become strict